# How to integrate Jenkins with Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have requirement for jmeter integrate with jenkins.
could you please some one help me on this.

I'm working on integrating performance tests with Jmeter.
My performance testing tool is JMeter and appserver is Jenkins

Answer (score 1):

1. JMeter is normal Java application which can be kicked off as a Jenkins build step via command-line using [jmeter.bat](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/bin/jmeter.bat) or [jmeter.sh](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_0/bin/jmeter.sh) scripts

   [image]
2. With regards to deeper JMeter and Jenkins integration there is [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-jenkins-performance-plugin) which can be either used for triggering a JMeter test

   [image]

   or publishing a performance report if you run JMeter using command-line build step or [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) or whatever

   [image]

As the result you will see performance trend charts at your build dashboard:

[image]